# My QuickSort and MergeSort are not functioning Properly

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, quicksort

My MergeSort and QuickSort call Insertion Sort when the segment is <= 15 indices in size. Insertion Sort works fine, Merge works fine, and Partition works fine, but my MergeSort and QuickSort do NOT work properly... They do not seem to sort at all... Please help:

**Here is my Insertion Sort Function, for context:**

```
int ndxCopy = 0, ndx, ndxSort, comp, result, ndxProper;
String sortMe = null;
for (ndx = (1 + firstIndex); ndx < numberToSort; ndx++) {
    sortMe = data.get(ndx);
    for (ndxSort = firstIndex; ndxSort < ndx; ndxSort++) {
        comp = sortMe.compareTo(data.get(ndxSort));
        if (comp < 0) {
            ndxProper = ndxSort;
            for (ndxCopy = ndx; ndxCopy > ndxProper; ndxCopy--)
                data.set(ndxCopy, data.get(ndxCopy - 1));

            data.set(ndxProper, sortMe);
        }
    }
}
```

**This my my Quicksort:**

```
if (numberToSort <= 15)
    insertionSort(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);
else {
    int partitionNdx = partition(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);

    int sizeLeft = (partitionNdx - firstIndex);
    int sizeRight = (numberToSort - sizeLeft - 1);

    quickSort(data, firstIndex, sizeLeft);
    quickSort(data, (firstIndex + sizeLeft + 1), sizeRight);
}
```

**This is my Partition:**
The medianOfThree method just random number generates 3 numbers within the range of indices, stores the 3 values at those indices, and uses the median as a pivot...

```
int pivotNdx = medianOfThree(data, firstIndex, numberToPartition);
String temp = data.get(firstIndex);
String pivot = data.get(pivotNdx);

data.set(firstIndex, pivot);
data.set(pivotNdx, temp);

int TooBigNdx = (firstIndex + 1), TooSmallNdx = (firstIndex + numberToPartition - 1);

while (TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx) {
    while ((TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx) && ((data.get(TooBigNdx)).compareTo(pivot) <= 0))
        TooBigNdx++;

    while ((TooSmallNdx > firstIndex) && ((data.get(TooSmallNdx)).compareTo(pivot) > 0))
        TooSmallNdx--;

    if (TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx) {
        temp = data.get(TooSmallNdx);
        String TooBig = data.get(TooBigNdx);

        data.set(TooSmallNdx, TooBig);
        data.set(TooBigNdx, temp);
    }

}

if (pivot.compareTo(data.get(TooSmallNdx)) >= 0) {
    temp = data.get(firstIndex);
    String TooSmall = data.get(TooSmallNdx);

    data.set(firstIndex, TooSmall);
    data.set(TooSmallNdx, temp);

    return TooSmallNdx;
} else
    return firstIndex;
```

**This is my MergeSort Method:**

```
if (numberToSort <= 15)
    insertionSort(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);
else {
    int sizeLeft = (numberToSort / 2);
    int sizeRight = (numberToSort / 2) + (numberToSort % 2);

    mergeSort(data, firstIndex, sizeLeft);
    mergeSort(data, (firstIndex + sizeLeft), sizeRight);

    merge(data, firstIndex, sizeLeft, sizeRight);
}
```

**This is my Merge Method:**

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
int ndxTemp = 0, ndxLeft = firstIndex, ndxRight = (firstIndex + leftSegmentSize), comp, ndx;
String left, right;
int sizeLeft = leftSegmentSize, sizeRight = rightSegmentSize;

while ((sizeLeft > 0) || (sizeRight > 0)) {
    if ((sizeLeft > 0) && (sizeRight > 0)) {
        left = data.get(ndxLeft);
        right = data.get(ndxRight);

        comp = left.compareTo(right);
        if (comp <= 0) {
            temp.add(data.get(ndxLeft++));
            sizeLeft--;
        } else {
            temp.add(data.get(ndxRight++));
            sizeRight--;
        }
    } else {
        if (sizeLeft > 0) {
            temp.add(data.get(ndxLeft++));
            sizeLeft--;
        } else {
            temp.add(data.get(ndxRight++));
            sizeRight--;
        }
    }
}

ndx = firstIndex;
for (ndxTemp = 0; ndxTemp < temp.size(); ndxTemp++)
    data.set(ndx++, temp.get(ndxTemp));
```

Please help me figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my problem turned out to be in this line of code:

```
for (ndx = (1 + firstIndex); ndx < numberToSort; ndx++) {
```

particularly :

```
ndx < numberToSort
```

this should instead be:

```
ndx < (numberToSort + firstIndex), as we are not necessarily starting at 0.
```